# Python RuntimeError target shapes do not match

Tags: python

While running a code I am getting this error. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? 
Error is RuntimeError: input and target shapes do not match: input [1 x 3 x 96 x 144], target [1 x 1 x 96 x 144] at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1532502421238/work/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/MSECriterion.cu:12

Answer (score 1):

Well, like the error already says you are trying to do some operation where the input [1 x 3 x 96 x 144] and the target [1 x 1 x 96 x 144] have different dimensions and the operation cannot be executed.

You cannot e.g. do matrix multiplication when dimensions are not matching.